# What is the purpose of using $0 as destination in MIPS

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

While I was studying about the conditions for detecting hazards while forwarding, I found this sentence very confusing.

> 'In the event that an instruction in the pipeline has $0 as its
>   destination (for example, `sll $0, $1, 2`), we want to avoid forwarding
>   its possibly nonzero result value.'

I thought register $0 cannot be written in a different value, so it's value is always 0. Then what is the use of `sll $0, $1, 2`, shifting left the value in $1 by 2 and storing it in $0, which cannot be changed? So how can $0 being as destination possibly be related to the need to forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"the need to forwarding" seems to indicate that you don't understand forwarding. It's an optimization. There is no "need" to do it.

Optimizations should not affect semantics. Storing a value to `$0` and subsequently reading the value of `$0` should return 0 per the usual semantics, **not** the previously-stored value. Yet forwarding would forward the stored value.

Now there's the question why `$0` can be used as the store location. That's just the RISC logic of having orthogonal instruction sets. On non-MIPS architectures, this is somewhat more useful as these discarded-value operations can still set flags.

Answer (score 1):

there can be events like when someone uses $0 as a destination, though it is often rare, but for example:
`sll $0, $1, 2`
`ori $2, $0, 60`
then there will be some data hazards since the value of $1 gets forwarded to the ori instruction even though $0 register is a constant 0, it can be fixed with ORing the register selector bits since or only gives 0 when the input is 0